# ASP.NET Core WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-core

I´m new to asp.net core, and I´m having trouble with injections on a web service.

```
namespace Web.WebServices
{
    public class InstallService : IService
    {
        private SQLContext _context;

        public InstallService(SQLContext context) 
        {
            _context = context;
        }  

        public string Fcn(string msg)
        {
            //Just for testing, the rest of the code is not altering the results
            return string.Join(string.Empty, msg.Reverse());
        }        
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Fcn(string msg);

    }
}
```

This is the ConfigureService method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddDbContext<SQLContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLConnection")));
        services.AddSoapExceptionTransformer((ex) => ex.Message);            
        services.AddScoped<IService, InstallService>();

    }
```

And the configure method:

```
app.UseSoapEndpoint<InstallService>("/ServicePath.asmx", new BasicHttpBinding());
```

Now the problem, when I try to consume the webservice I get the error:

> "System.ServiceModel.FaultException. Non-static method requires a target"

And if I remove the injection the webservice works fine.

```
namespace Web.WebServices
{
    public class InstallService : IService
    {
        public string Fcn(string msg)
        {
            return string.Join(string.Empty, msg.Reverse());
        }        
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Fcn(string msg);

    }
}
```

And the Configure service method:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddDbContext<SQLContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLConnection")));
        services.AddSoapExceptionTransformer((ex) => ex.Message);            
        services.AddScoped(new InstallService());

    }
```

But I need to use the webService to save data to the SQL Server.

I´m almost sure something wrong is not right, but I can´t figure it out.

Comment: You are using ASP.NET Core to host WCF services? Why not just create a WCF on ASP.NET project?

Comment: Do you use [SoapCore](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore) or implement your own `UseSoapEndpoint`?

Comment: services.AddScoped(new InstallService()); is your problem, don't do a new here

Comment: I already have this webserver running, so I´m trying to append the webservice in it. Sorry, forgot to tell I´m using SoapCore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using [SoapCore](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore), try to configure service like

```
            services.AddScoped<IService, InstallService>();
```

And then use service like below:

```
            app.UseSoapEndpoint<IService>("/ServicePath.asmx", new BasicHttpBinding());
```

Comment: I´ll try to implment the interface instead of the class, get back to you as soon as I try that. Thanks

Comment: THANKS! That was it, saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems difference between

```
public class InstallService : IService
{
    private SQLContext _context;

    public InstallService(SQLContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
    }  
}
```

And

```
public class InstallService : IService
{
}
```

You got this exception.

> "System.ServiceModel.FaultException. Non-static method requires a target"

Probably you didn't get `SQLContext` instance.

Please check out `Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLConnection"))` in your code.

[How to read connection string in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083372/how-to-read-connection-string-in-net-core)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

Correct me if I'm wrong. :p

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I´m already using the SQLcontext in several other places, and it´s working fine.