# How to implement the IConfiguration interface in ASP.NET Core for Dapper usage?

Tags: asp.net-core, orm, dapper

I am familiar with using ASP.NET Core with EF Core, where you just define your `DBContext` in the `ConfigureServices` method from `Startup.cs` for DI, like so:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
```

However, I have been asked to add Dapper to this project (it will still use EF) but I can't even fetch the connection string. I found Brad Patton's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083372/how-to-read-connection-string-in-net-core) to be along the lines of what I had in mind, but he leaves the setup of the `Configuration` object up to the reader:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    // Add the whole configuration object here.
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
}
```

After googling around for a couple of hours, I still have no idea of how to implement the `IConfiguration` interface. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ASP.NET Core 2.x you no longer need to register the `IConfiguration` type yourself. Instead, the framework will already register it with the dependency injection container for you. So you can just inject `IConfiguration` in your services directly.

You can also take a look at the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to see how to implement the configuration for your own service layer. So you could do it like this:

```
services.Configure<MyDatabaseOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
});
```

Assuming a `MyDatabaseOptions` type that you inject into your service using the options pattern.