# There is no integrated security keywork?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, connection

I'm trying to connect to the local database instance that visual studios provides, I setup a connection string in the `appsettings.json` however, it keeps failing at the integrated security keyword, it says it doesn't exist. However if I take it out, the response gets a timeout because there was no pre-authorization handshake which is because I set my `dbcontext` to `identitydbcontext` so I would need to specify the integrated security = true keyword but alas I'm stuck

This is the default connection string:

```
"DefaultConnection":"Server=(localdb)\\\\
mssqllocaldb;Database=ChatAppTr;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
Integrated Security=True;"
```

This is how I setup the database context for my web app:

```
///Specify what type of user you want in identity context:
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) :
        base( options){ }
        /// Registers models to AppdbContext
        public DbSet<Chat> Chats { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Messages> Messages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I expected it to just connect to the `localdb` instance but nothing happened.

Comment: Did you set your connection to Context in Startup.cs? Like this: `services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext >(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`

Comment: this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083372/how-to-read-connection-string-in-net-core

Comment: Yeah i set that all up, i'm not sure i think theres something in the  connection string. What my idea is its to connect to a local instance of db (not the sql server one)  @SelimYıldız

Comment: I don't have problems with the configuration i understand the whole adding to services bit and selecting options all of that. It just i dont get how i used to connect to the local instance? @MojtabaNava