# Adding a custom provider to Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following code in my Program.cs:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)            
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(b => b
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddMyCustomConfiguration(o => o.UseSqlServer(
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:MyDatabase"))))                
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

My `appsettings.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDatabase": "connectionstring"
  }
}
```

However, `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:MyDatabase")` is returning null. I was under the impression that `AddEnvironmentVariables` would load the necassary variables. Is this not the case / how can I get this to load the connection string?

Answer (score 1):

For getting `ConnectionStrings` from `appsettings.json`, you should use `GetConnectionString` instead of reading environment.

Try something like below:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)            
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(b => {
            b.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            var connectionString = b.Build().GetConnectionString("MyDatabase");
            .AddMyCustomConfiguration(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
    })              
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: This still returns null

Comment: @CuriousDev Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Thank you for this @Edward, It works!!!! I think OP didn't realize .Build() part of it

Answer (score 0):

See this example

```
 public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
  {
    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

    config.AddJsonFile("application.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    config.AddEnvironmentVariables("ASPNETCORE_");
    config.AddCommandLine(args);
  })
  .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

here you have the link to the article https://www.johanohlin.com/blog/configuration-providers-in-aspnet-core/

Comment: This doesn't make any difference.  I've tried various combinations on the approach, but no luck.  Obviously AddEnvironmentVariables("ASPNETCORE_") is no good to me, so I just load them all

Answer (score 0):

You've put your settings into JSON config, not into env var(s). This is why `GetEnvironmentVariable()` returns nothing. And ASP.Net Core is not intended to export your config to env vars unless you did that explicitly (let say, via `SetEnvironmentVariable()` or an equivalent).

If you actually intend to just read a connection string value, take a look on this topc [How to read connection string in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083372/how-to-read-connection-string-in-net-core/40844342)