# I have a problem with SQL Server connection string

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, swagger

When I run the api from Visual Studio without a debug, I always get an error when I enter the values ​​I want in swagger.io.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteScalarImpl[T](IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 2876 at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteScalar[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 493
> at API.Data_Access.DataAccess.IsEmailAvailable(String email) in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\rent-car\CarAPI\API\DataAccess\DataAccess.cs:line 52
> at API.Controllers.CarsController.CreateAccount(User user) in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\rent-car\CarAPI\API\Controllers\CarsController.cs:line 23
> at lambda_method2(Closure , Object , Object[] )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

**HEADERS**

```
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:7055
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/112.0.1722.64
:method: POST
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: tr,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: https://localhost:7055
Referer: https://localhost:7055/swagger/index.html
Content-Length: 220
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Microsoft Edge";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

Here is my code:

`Dataacces.cs`:

```
using API.Models;
using Dapper;
using MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace API.Data_Access
{
  public class DataAccess : IDataAccess
  {
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly string DbConnection;

    public DataAccess(IConfiguration _configuration)
    {
      configuration = _configuration;
      DbConnection = configuration["connectionStrings: DBConnect"] ?? "";
    }

    public int CreateUser(User user)
    {
      var result = 0;

      using (var connection = new SqlConnection(DbConnection))
      {
        var paramaters = new
        {
          fn = user.FirstName,
          ln = user.LastName,
          em = user.Email,
          mb = user.Mobile,
          pwd = user.Password,
          blk = user.Blocked,
          act = user.Active,
          con = user.CreatedOn,
          type = user.UserType.ToString(), 
        };

        var sql = "insert into Users (FirstName, LastName, Email, Mobile, Password, Blocked, Active, CreatedOn) values (@fn, @ln, @em, @mb, @pwd, @blk, @act, @con);";

        result = connection.Execute(sql, paramaters);
      }

      return result;
    }

    public bool IsEmailAvailable(string email)
    {
      var result = false;

      using (var connection = new SqlConnection(DbConnection))
      {
        result = connection.ExecuteScalar<bool>("select count(*) from Users where Email=@email;", new { email });
      }

      return !result;
    }
  }
}
```

User.cs

```
namespace API.Models
{
  public class User
  {
    public float Id { get; set; } = 0;
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Mobile { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool Blocked { get; set; } = false;
    public bool Active { get; set; } = true;
    public float Fine { get; set; } = 0;
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
    public string CreatedOn { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBConnect": "Data Source=DESKTOP-NI7D77J\\SQLEXPRESS01;User ID=ahmet; Password = ********;"
  }
}
```

IDataAccess.cs

```
using API.Controllers;
using API.Models;

namespace API.Data_Access
{
  public interface IDataAccess
  {
    int CreateUser(User user);
    bool IsEmailAvailable(string email);
  }
}
```

Carscontroller.cs

```
using API.Data_Access;
using API.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace API.Controllers
{
  [Route("api/[controller]")] 
  [ApiController]
  public class CarsController : ControllerBase
  {
    private readonly IDataAccess cars;

    public CarsController(IDataAccess cars)
    {
      this.cars = cars;
    }

    [HttpPost("CreateAccount")]
    public IActionResult CreateAccount(User user)
    {
      if (!cars.IsEmailAvailable(user.Email))
      {
        return Ok("Email uygun değil");
      }

      user.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
      user.UserType = UserType.USER;
      cars.CreateUser(user);

      return Ok("Hesap başarılı bir şekilde oluşturuldu!");
    }
  }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using API.Data_Access;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// DI
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataAccess, DataAccess>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Modelbase.cs

```
namespace API.Models
{ 
   public class ModelBase
    {

    public int Id { get; set; }

     }

}
```

UserType.cs

```
namespace API.Models
{ 
  public enum UserType
{

  USER,
  ADMIN
}

}
```

When I asked ChatGPT, it told me to add a connection string, but even though I added it, it always gave the same error.

[image]

The values from swagger.io

Comment: Yes, i tried this but not worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read connection string in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083372/how-to-read-connection-string-in-net-core)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is here:

`DbConnection = configuration["connectionStrings: DBConnect"] ?? "";`

I would suggest you start by researching how to read properties from config. Add a breakpoint or some logging after this line so you can check that you are reading the connection string correctly.

You might find that something like the following works:

`DbConnection = configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:DBConnect");`

(The exact syntax required will depend on your environment and frameworks - you don't mention these in your question.)

Also, you should probably throw an exception if the result is `null` or empty, since none of the rest of your code will work if you don't have a connection string.

Comment: I applied the code you suggested, but nothing changed. In fact, I tried many methods, but as I said, I could not prevent this problem in any way.

Comment: But this time error says Invalid object name 'Users'.

Comment: You say that "nothing changed" but then you say that the error has changed. This means something has changed! It sounds like the code I suggested has worked exactly as intended, but now you have a completely different problem, probably in the query `select count(*) from Users...`. If you'd like some help with that, I suggest you accept this answer and ask a new question.

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't read the error in detail.