# WebAPI Core 2 Multiple connection string with same context

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am developing webapi with some knowledge of Core 2.0 
I need to create two link to produce different result from different database both database schema are the same.

Like https://localhost:5000/m/University
or https://localhost:5000/v/University
They both fire in different database with same webapi application and give result it. I can produced result but I have to either create two webapi project or change connection string ("MConn") in Start up class.

---

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => { options.AutomaticAuthentication = true; });
        services.AddDbContext<PIDBContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MConn")));
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

---

Could you help me how to use same Webapi project with different connection string based on Https request?

Thanks

Comment: See [my question, how to dynamically change connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816215/dynamically-change-connection-string-in-asp-net-core), might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I have at least 50 controller with different result produce with those controller route. That means need to change lot.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution:

1. Create `DbContextFactory`

   ```
   public static class DbContextFactory
   {
       public static Dictionary<string, string> ConnectionStrings { get; set; }

       public static void SetConnectionString(Dictionary<string, string> connStrs)
       {
           ConnectionStrings = connStrs;
       }

       public static AppContext Create(string connid)
       {
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connid))
           {
               var connStr = ConnectionStrings[connid];
               var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppContext >();
               optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connStr);
               var db = new AppContext (optionsBuilder.Options);
               return db;
           }
           else
           {
               throw new ArgumentNullException("Connection failed becuase of no Connection ID");
           }
      } 
   }
   ```
2. Project Json file:

   ```
   {
       "ConnectionStrings": {
       "Sample1con": "your 1st connection string",
       "Sample2con": "your 2nd connection string"
       }
   }
   ```
3. In Configure method in Startup class declare Dictionary

   ```
   Dictionary<string, string> connStrs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   connStrs.Add("p", Configuration.GetConnectionString("Sample1con"));
   connStrs.Add("m", Configuration.GetConnectionString("Sample2con"));
   DbContextFactory.SetConnectionString(connStrs);
   ```
4. In action usage

   ```
   var _context = DbContextFactory.Create(db); ///Db would be your URL string.
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to have two links? If not, can't you achieve that by doing following.

- Pass a parameter to your route, and use that route to decide which context to use.
- So for https://localhost:5000/University/m you will use one context and for https://localhost:5000/University/v you will use another context.
- As both the databases have same schema there wouldn't be any problem parsing the results to same object models.

Comment: This is nice way to approach if only small change in few controller. I have 50 or more controller and multiple method as well. So There would be lots of duplicate code. Is this only option?