# asp.net core how to change connection string at run time from entity framework (after login)

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 3.0 web application. I would like to change the connection string at run time once login is successful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically change connection string in Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816215/dynamically-change-connection-string-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816215/dynamically-change-connection-string-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Without seeing how your context is setup, it's hard to give a concrete answer.
However, in most cases, you can just create a new database context and pass the connection string into the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO,you could not change the `services.AddDbContext<T>` at runtime.A workaround is that you add a `DBContextFactory` to create new dbcontext object when you login successfully.

Refer to following steps:

1.Create a `DBContextFactory.cs`

```
public static class DbContextFactory
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> ConnectionStrings { get; set; }

    public static void SetConnectionString(Dictionary<string, string> connStrs)
    {
        ConnectionStrings = connStrs;
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create(string connid)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connid))
        {
            var connStr = ConnectionStrings[connid];
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connStr);
            return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ConnectionId");
        }
    }
}
```

2.Intialize DbContextFactory in startup `Configure`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> connStrs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        connStrs.Add("DB1", "Your connection string 1");
        connStrs.Add("DB2", "Your connection string 2");
        DbContextFactory.SetConnectionString(connStrs);
        //other middlewares
    }
```

3.Usage

```
if(status)
{
   var dbContext = DbContextFactory.Create("DB2");//get the dbcontext with connection string 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After login you can save the **connection string** to session, cookie or your preferred storage then edit the **DbContext** as follow (I suppose that you have chosen **session**):

```
public class GroupwareContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;
    public GroupwareContext(DbContextOptions<GroupwareContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor = null)
        : base(options)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext;
    }

    public GroupwareContext(DbContextOptions<GroupwareContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (_httpContext != null) {
            if (_httpContext.Session.GetString("connectionString") != null)
            {
                var connectionString = (string)_httpContext.Session.GetString("connectionString");
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            }
        }

    }

    public DbSet<Account> Account { get; set; }
}
```