# Make dynamically HangFire connection string .NetCore

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, hangfire

I have a project using HangFire for a background job and I need to change the connection string dynamically without needing to change the code manually every time I want to run this job to any customer as I've many customers and many Databases as well
I've done this to the normal connection in the startup and DbContext based on this solution and works like a charm
[Dynamically change connection string in Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57064965/13206244)

and I want to do the same with the HangFire connection, and this is the code I'm using now

```
            services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration.UseStorage(
            new MySqlStorage("server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;database=0046696-k; Allow User Variables=True",
            new MySqlStorageOptions()
            {
                TransactionIsolationLevel = (System.Transactions.IsolationLevel?)IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
                QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                JobExpirationCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
                CountersAggregateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = true,
                DashboardJobListLimit = 50000,
                TransactionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                TablesPrefix = "Hangfire"
            })));
        services.AddHangfireServer();
```

Comment: https://www.automatetheplanet.com/change-config-file-at-runtime/

Comment: Then do not hard code the connection string. store it in the appsettings.json file and load it at startup. That way you only need to edit the settings file.

Comment: @JimG. great article, thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not hard code the connection string.

Store it in the appsettings.json file

For example

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Hangfire": "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;database=0046696-k; Allow User Variables=True"
  }

  /* other settings */
}
```

and load it at startup.

```
//...Assume IConfiguration Configuration is loaded

//...

string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Hangfire"); //<-- NOTE

services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration.UseStorage(
    new MySqlStorage(connectionString, //<-- NOTE
    new MySqlStorageOptions() {
        TransactionIsolationLevel = (System.Transactions.IsolationLevel?)IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
        QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
        JobExpirationCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
        CountersAggregateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = true,
        DashboardJobListLimit = 50000,
        TransactionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        TablesPrefix = "Hangfire"
    })));

services.AddHangfireServer();

//...
```

That way you only need to edit the settings file as desired.

If the options need to change dynamically as well then add a section in the settings to hold the desired options and load them in Startup.

Comment: I didn't actually think it would be that simple, thank you