# Initializing a DBConext with a different connection string on a per user basis in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dbcontext

I need to be able create a DBContext with a specific DB connection string depending on the logged in user.

Users login via a JWT token at which point the application makes a call to a 3rd party to determine which database they should be connected to.

I am currently registering my ApplicationDBContext at startup:

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestDbConString"),
                    h => h.UseHierarchyId()
                ));
```

I also have this service:

```
services.
...
.onAuthenticated(async c => {

    await getConnectionData(); // Returns the connection string. This can take a few seconds the first time subsequently it returns cached data.

})
```

Obviously I need to change things up a bit. How would you go about registering ApplicationDBContext with the correct/custom connection string?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my poor attempt at setting up a DbContextFactory.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyApp.Models;

namespace MyApp.Data
{

    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>
    {


        public ApplicationDbContextFactory test(){
            return new ApplicationDbContextFactory();
        }

        public AppDbContext CreateDbContext()
        {

            string ConnectionString = "";


            //Magic here to get my ConnectionString.

            DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext> options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
            options.UseSqlServer(
                ConnectionString,
                h => h.UseHierarchyId()
            );

            return new AppDbContext(options.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup,cs

```
                services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContextFactory>();
                services.AddTransient(provider => provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContextFactory>()!.CreateDbContext());
```

I am now getting an error:

```
Unexpected Execution Error : No service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[MyApp.Data.AppDbContext]' has been registered.
```

Update #2
This fixed it:

Startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<IDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>, ApplicationDbContextFactory>();
```

Comment: You need to create your own implementation of the DBContextFactory which will initialise a context based on the connection string which could come from anywhere. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816215/dynamically-change-connection-string-in-asp-net-core) might help.

Comment: DBContextFactory doesn't accept any parameters to specify which tenant you'll be creating that dbcontext for, though, you're better off creating your own factory.

Comment: Oh I thought you meant like `IDbContextFactory`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor.

Comment: EFCore 5 can change the connStr on an existing context; are you using EFC5?

Comment: https://blog.jeremylikness.com/blog/multitenancy-with-ef-core-in-blazor-server-apps/. Although the post is written for Blazor server, it still applies to DbContext.

Comment: @AliK I believe that sounds like the best option.

Comment: `services.AddTransient<IDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>ApplicationDbContextFactory>();`?