# .NET Core HttpContext is empty during getting DB name in Startup

Tags: .net-core

I have .NET Core app with dynamic DB, that I get from http request (subdomain).
And I do the following in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
    {
        var httpContext = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
        //todo get subdomain
                
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataContext").Replace(":dbname", dbName));
    });
    ...
}
```

But `httpContext` variable is null. Why is it null and how can I resolve it?

I looked at this link [Dynamically change connection string in Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816215/dynamically-change-connection-string-in-asp-net-core)
but it seems nothing works from there

Comment: I think you have to use an environment variable to store the dbname

Comment: @dofra I would be appreciate the example how it will work in my case.

Comment: yeah sure. Can you tell where you are deploying the application? On-Prem, Azure app service, docker?

Comment: Azure app service

Answer (score 1):

An `HttpContext` only exists when there is a request, that's why you won't get any outside of one.

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo, but what's the best way to get DB name in my case then?

Comment: See the approach I followed in my library SharedFlat: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/sharedflat-and-databases